# Why does this function wont return the results?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I'm writing my own class to manage mongodb queries within express framework.

This how the class looks like

```
var PostModel = function(){};

PostModel.prototype.index = function(db){
  db.open(function(err,db){
    if(!err){

      db.collection('post',function(err,collection){

        collection.find().toArray(function(err,posts){
          if(!err){
            db.close();
            return posts;
          }
        });  
      });
    }
  });
};
```

When I call this function:

```
// GET /post index action
app.get('/post',function(req,res){

  postModel = new PostModel();
  var posts = postModel.index(db);
  res.json(posts); 

});
```

I dont know why seems like the function index did not return anything.

But if I change the index function like this

```
var PostModel = function(){};

PostModel.prototype.index = function(db){
  db.open(function(err,db){
    if(!err){

      db.collection('post',function(err,collection){

        collection.find().toArray(function(err,posts){
          if(!err){
            db.close();
            console.log(posts);
          }
        });  
      });
    }
  });
};
```

NOTE the console.log instead of the return. With this changes I can see into the terminal all the post I wanted. That's beacause the function retrive all the post as it should.

The problem is that it does not return the post :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using async functions, they all get callbacks, so you'll need to use a callback too:

```
var PostModel = function(){};

PostModel.prototype.index = function(db, callback){
  db.open(function(err,db){
    if(!err){

      db.collection('post',function(err,collection){

        collection.find().toArray(function(err,posts){
          if(!err){
            db.close();
            callback(posts);
          }
        });  
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks :) You helped me in understing a lot of things :)